# Union type of two different useState setter functions gives error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, union-types

I have two different components that have one prop in common in their states, in this minimum example it will be the `pictures` prop which is an array of strings:

Apartment.ts

```ts
type ApartmentType = {
    landlord: string;
    pictures: string[];
}

function Apartment () {
    const [ apartmentData, setApartmentData ] = useState<ApartmentType>({
        landlord: 'juan',
        pictures: [ 'url1', 'url2' ]
    })

    return (
        <h1>Apartment</h1>
        <FileUploader setFunction={setApartmentData} />
    )
}
```

House.ts

```ts
type HouseType = {
    owner: string;
    pictures: string[];
}

function House () {
    const [ houseData, setHouseData ] = useState<HouseType>({
        owner: 'Jhon',
        pictures: [ 'url1', 'url2' ]
    })

    return (
        <h1>House</h1>
        <FileUploader setFunction={setHouseData} />
    )
}
```

As you can see I'm adding a `FileUploader` component which will update the `pictures` array of its parent using the set function that comes with the `useState` hook:

```ts
type FileUploaderProps = {
    setFunction: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HouseType> | React.SetStateAction<ApartmentType>>
}

function FileUploader ({ setFunction }: FileUploaderProps) {
    function updatePictures () {
        setFunction((prevValue: any) => ({ ...prevValue, pictures: [ ...prevValue.pictures, 'newUrl1', 'newUrl2'] }))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>File Uploader</h1>
            <button type='button' onClick={updatePictures}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But here is where the issue appears, in `Apartment` and `House` for the `setFunction` prop in `FileUploader` TS is giving me this error:

```ts
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<HouseType>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<ApartmentType> | SetStateAction<HouseType>>'.
  Type 'SetStateAction<ApartmentType> | SetStateAction<HouseType>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<HouseType>'.
    Type 'ApartmentType' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<HouseType>'.
      Property 'owner' is missing in type 'ApartmentType' but required in type 'HouseType'
```

What I'm doing wrong?, I though that typing the `setFunction` prop in `FileUploader` as:

```ts
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HouseType> | React.SetStateAction<ApartmentType>>
```

would be sufficient to account for the two possibilities but it is not.

Here is a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC%20cAZlBCHAORSoYsDcAUDzAE8wVAIJgUsEEgB28ALy4ecZXAA2KaQBNV0TQC44hGFGDSA5rxVwwwDPnaEDRk%20YDaAXV7U%20dfNIzAENJwYhIwUrJwABQAlIpWaEFGcK5wKOKSMjAAIhQo2MQwoZmyueRw7nAKRKTklAA8xeFZAHxROEpWKupaOlD6rABW%20BosmJ1d1rYw9kiOKaz2qgCMY4tQqgBMLBUTNDF77DNQwVF7VvWawABuLeeTcPUAFsstAMJMkNJZIfUA9C87g8uvUAGLAVRIACqYB0KE0SCghiQMFBfgCQTkOEKTQiOTytD%20QIe-yutz2B28-CEVAAEhAalV4ioIAB3b5QJzGUwWPY2OwOLkuMweLw%20dEwQLBemM2LM5SJaTJVJPBnEMr5ZEwGXqvIVJk1MgUJD1HVINodYFsjkGFgAKVV0jG92U-OOcwMqRYS1W2G9G22uys1AOViO9lOLseZOJwOUz1eH3AQR%20ACF-oCoxdwZCYXCEUjCmj-JLMdiUWaNYTYyC-jGKTwqYJhHAc9DYRB4YiAAqMMCEJmWlRFiVSgzIdAwAB02WAhHEMDQT3qE4wU5IKKNlBEGOkprV5rgAB9EBxpxuYFukDvS3vca07lTfCWpa2Ie384jongRy%20gjQDDbPNOwLXsIH7OIh2UZ9dwIMBNGNbtplmAc5Sgrpf13KIojAdhrgANRQVR8CQAwNAEOI5Bab84CnOjcKQAiiJI7A3RQz1aPovDCOIpApzYhw-W%20VkoQ2X1WGE0SthYSoQ1DFRvDDFEI2iKNLhuGtgQTFo2zgYCuygDNXizFR6gAI3wGAYH-II3lUWwAGssXweDEOQhxqBafTNDgJCBRNP4LKsoJNNMusNIbaggA) for a playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making some confusion with the template types and Union type in "wrong" place (`React.SetStateAction<Apartment>` and `React.SetStateAction<House>`). It would be best if you made the function a Union type such as:

```
type FileUploaderProps = {
    setFunction: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<House>> | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Apartment>>
}
```